# I am fetching a problem in laravel API . That is "ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$id"

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am trying to fetch data by GET method. But I donot get any output. What is the wrong in my code.
This is index funtion in controller:

```
 public function index(){
        $post = Post::all();
        return  PostResource::collection($post);
    }
```

this is PostResource code :

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'user' =>  new UserCollection($this->user),
            'title' => $this->title,
            'description' => $this->description,
        ];
    }
```

this is UserResource code:

```
  public function toArray($request)
    {
         return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email
        ];
    }
```

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Comment: Which of these lines causes that problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: 'user' =>  new UserCollection($this->user) , this is the line.

Comment: I want to fatch user information of every post.

Comment: You can do this with [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) - `$posts = Post::with('user')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Try eager-loading the user relationship in the controller:

```php
 public function index(){
     $post = Post::with('user')->all();
     return  PostResource::collection($post);
}
```

If you, however, do now want to eager-load the relationship, then in your `PostResource`, do this:

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'user' =>  new UserCollection($this->user()),
        'title' => $this->title,
        'description' => $this->description,
    ];
}
``
```

Comment: It did not solve my problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you share the response you're getting.